# App Engine: Mechanics of creating a unique entity if it doesn't exist

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

We have an issue where we want to lazily create an entity if it does not exist. There is some discussion going on about how to do this and I would like to clarify some things around app engine transactions. I will limit my query to single entity group transactions.

I am using Go in my examples, but I hope the code is clear enough for non-Go programmers.

My understanding is that a transaction, on a single entity group, will succeed only if the entity group is not modified externally during the transaction. The 'entity group timestamp' indicating when an entity group was changed is stored in the root entity of the entity group. So during a transaction the current 'entity group timestamp' is read and the transaction can only succeed if it hasn't changed by the end of the transaction.

```
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Counter", "mycounter", 0, nil)
count := new(Counter)
err := datastore.RunInTransaction(c, func(c appengine.Context) error {
  err := datastore.Get(c, key, count)
  if err != nil && err != datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
    return err
  }
  count.Count++
  _, err = datastore.Put(c, key, count)
  return err
}, nil)
```

In the example above (taken from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/transactions) there are two non-error cases, I can see:

- The Get succeeds and the 'entity group timestamp' on the counter can be used to ensure no other transactions update the counter during this transaction.
- The Get fails with `ErrNoSuchEntity` and the Put is used to store the counter for the first time.

In the second case it is possible that another identical transaction is running. If both transactions' Get return `ErrNoSuchEntity` how does the datastore ensure that only one put succeeds? I would expect there to be no "entity group timestamp" in the datastore to test against?

Does the transaction know that it needs to test for the non-existence of the counter in order for the Put and the entire transaction to succeed?

Is there a chance in this case for two transactions to succeed and for one Put to overwrite the other?

If there is documentation, or videos etc, around the mechanism that controls this I would love to read it.

Comment: This description of a transaction might help clarify my question. It lays out, more clearly than I have, the user of 'timestamp's in app engine transactions.


"When a transaction starts, App Engine uses optimistic concurrency control by checking the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. Upon commiting a transaction for the entity groups, App Engine again checks the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. If it has changed since our initial check, an error is returned."

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/transactions

Comment: Jaime and Clément are right. when the two txes commit and recheck the entity group, one will find no timestamp and commit successfully, the other will find the first's timestamp and fail. the datastore API code will then retry it.

Comment: background: [paper on megastore](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html), the storage system that powers the datastore.

[another description of datastore transactions](https://snarfed.org/datastore_talk.html), start on slide 49.

[source code underlying python NDB's `get_or_insert`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#3428), which implements this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question we must dig deeper, into the source code of the dev datastore, fortunately for us it is very well documented, just take a look at [`LiveTxn._GrabSnapshot`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py#1437):

> Gets snapshot for this reference, creating it if necessary.
>
> If no snapshot has been set for reference's entity group, a snapshot is taken and stored for future reads (this also sets the read position), and a CONCURRENT_TRANSACTION exception is thrown if we no longer have a consistent snapshot.

So the edge case is slightly different than what you were speculating: both transactions will create a fresh timestamp, and then things will work like usual. In the case you were putting forth, the 2nd transaction will retry, and the counter will be incremented twice.

There's no in-depth documentation about how transactions work that i'm aware of, at least not *this deep*, but the source code is actually not *that* hard to read; in this instance you can follow the trail of the `CONCURRENT_TRANSACTION` error.

Comment: Ok, so my reading of that code looks like.
1: 
The Get(...) will generate a snapshot for the key (or more precisely its entity group).
2: 
The Put(...) will not generate or check a snapshot value.
3: 
The final Commit(...) call will perform a check to ensure the snapshot value hasn't changed, and for the slower of the two transactions it will detect the other Put and fail.

Comment: I believe that's an accurate description.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I'm trawling through the go code now to see if I can piece it together at that end as well. I really appreciate your knowledge here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/transactions#Go_Isolation_and_consistency):

> Inside of transactions, serializable isolation is enforced.

I suggest reading up a bit on the linked [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability), but in brief, the datastore will make sure that the final outcome is as if the two transactions ran in sequence.

Having both transactions write a new, zeroed, counter is **not** a possible outcome.

> Does the transaction know that it needs to test for the non-existence of the counter in order for the Put and the entire transaction to succeed?

In a way **yes**: the transaction can succeed on first try only if there was no overlapping transaction touching the same key.

> Is there a chance in this case for two transactions to succeed and for one Put to overwrite the other?

**No**, if the two transactions timeframes overlap, then the last one to commit will fail, be eventually retried and then will see the existing counter and increment it.

Comment: Thanks Clément, I appreciate that datastore transactions are serializing and this property certainly provides the guarantee I am after. However, I am confused because there are quite a few descriptions of transactions for the datastore and megastore which do not appear to cover the case where there is no key in the datastore from which to take a timestamp. I was looking for a clarification around how this case is handled. For instance here is the megastore description of a transaction. From Ryan's linked paper.

Comment: 1. Read: Obtain the timestamp and log position of the last committed transaction.
2. Application logic: Read from Bigtable and gather writes into a log entry.
3. Commit: Use Paxos to achieve consensus for append- ing that entry to the log.
4. Apply: Write mutations to the entities and indexes in Bigtable.
5. Clean up: Delete data that is no longer required.

In the case given above there is no 'last committed transaction' from which to obtain a timestamp. I was trying to understand how this case is handled.

Comment: For new entity groups, the write-ahead log doesn't exist yet, so the timestamp and log position are both 0. In your example above, both transactions will compete for the same, first, log position, but only one will win.